# How to make 3-state button in React?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, button

Is it possible to make 3-state button in React?

I don't mean "toggle switch button" - I mean regular button that will toggle between 3 different states every time user clicks it.

How can I make such a button?

Comment: Also [React toggle tri-state component](/q/68240531/15497888) and [Implementing a custom component for a tri state switch with states(enabled, partial, disabled) using ReactJS](/q/57477376/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Used three states by number like (0,1,2) as in two states we toggle between true false,

Check this sandbox for understanding as button toggles between three colours, you can use same logic for more different state decisions,

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);

function toggleState() {
if (state === 0 || state === 1) {
  setState(state + 1);
 }else {
  setState(0);
}}
```

Better solution would be to make more scalable as suggested by @Henry Ecker , setState(prevState => (prevState + 1) % 3);

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-tdd-iph378?file=/src/App.js

This just an example for how to have toggle between three states, you can use same logic to fullfill your requirement

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code directly into the answer as formatted text.

Comment: Modulus to bound the value would make the solution more scalable: `setState(prevState => (prevState + 1) % 3);` instead of the if-else in `toggleState`

Comment: Yes agreed, this is just for 3 state requirement to get the intuition, but modulus solution is way better, thanks for adding that